# Putting large text in Texblock and ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, scrollviewer, textblock

I have this PivotItem:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Biografie">
       <StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="textScroller" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Biography}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
 </controls:PivotItem>
```

and in Biography I have large text (about 1575 chars). I can scroll with scrollviewer but I didn´t see all text. It just stop few sentences before end. I found that textblock don´t display more then 5000 chars or something like that but I have much less. Anyone know where can I have problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit to 2048 px height. Look at this to workaround: [Creating Scrollable TextBlock for WP7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)

Comment: Looks good. Did it work for you, Libor? Having the same issue and discovered that the Emulator does not clip it, only when running the same code on a real device it is clipped by the platform ...